# Most efficient way to pull items from database based on their x,y location in a grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, database-design, position, parse-platform

I'm working on an iOS game where players villages are displayed on a large kingdom map. Each village has a x,y location on that map, and each village is stored as an object in a database on a server (Parse.com).

What I want to be able to do is pull down all the villages around the current players village. Usually this would be straightforward as you would just use the shortest distance algorithm, but to use that I would need to download all of the villages in the database, and then run the algorithm on each one, then sort them according to distance from player, which is not exactly a quick/efficient way of doing it. So does anyone know of a more refined/efficient way of doing the above? what would be great would be to be able to pull down the villages around the current player actually in the query to the database, kill 2 birds with one stone so to speak, but I can't see any way to do that. I suspect the answer lies in perhaps storing more information about the location of the village in the database, so a query could pull the closest ones down without having to run an algorithm to make it happen.

Any ideas?

I'll leave this question up as I'm still interested in how to do it with basic math, the Manhatten distance approach should be ok, but for anyone using Parse.com it might be possible to use geoPoints maybe? It's a nutty idea, but I'm going to try it.

Comment: Surely the x and y values are in the DB so you can query them (and use > and < in the query) ?

Comment: You could do a query, to see if a number is greater or less then another number, and perhaps do that with one query on both the x and y int's, but that just gives you an absolute value, that's not the distance between points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get all villages within D units of [Manhattan distance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) away from point (X,Y) by  querying for all villages matching the constraints X - D < x and x < X + D and Y - D < y and y < Y + D.

You can then do further filtering based on [Euclidean distance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) on the client if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, Any chance of putting that into some pseudo code? Obj-c ideally :)

Comment: @Phil: any specific area where you're having difficulty? IMO, the description I gave is pretty clear and should be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have a go at using Parse.com's geoPoints see if that works out.

Comment: Try using the whereKey:nearGeoPoint types of query constraints - you'll get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm going to try, saved me a lot of messing around!

Comment: @Phil be aware that GeoPoints are proper latitude/longitude values. Representing numbers as (lat,long). The distance between (0,0) and (0,+1) is 111.312km (going from east to west along the equator). The distance between (+90,0) and (+90,+1) is 0km (North pole). If your villages are based on real world Earth coordinates, this is fine, if your villages are based on a normal "grid", you will run into problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was just working that out, I wanted a very large grid, say 5mil by 5mil, so I was just going to divide the lat,long numbers by 5mil to get the cell point so to speak. So you're saying that the geoPoints are based upon a curved surface, so if I just try to use them in a grid sense it won't work? The problem I have is that the kingdom map will keep growing according to the number of players there are so I wanted to set the start size of the map as a huge area, so I would never run out of space basically.

Comment: Hey Phil - Yep, geo points are based on the Earth's surface. If you wanted to get mathematical, you could do inverse mappings from your "grid-space" to "earth-space", this would allow you to take advantage of Parse's GeoPoints query functionality, but it would probably make your code overly complex (although it wouldn't to encapsulate this translation into a class). It would be a pain to debug, so I'd recommend against it though. I would just run with the original answer by Lie.

Comment: Also, depending on the number of villages you are expecting to have, you could create a new table, which is essentially a village distance matrix. Your rows may get too wide if the number of villages is high. There are a few other smart ways you could store your village distance info in a table however. This would let you very cleanly do queries for "closest X Villages to Village A, sorted by distance".

Comment: Ah ok so you're saying don't use geoPoints? couldn't I set my first village at lat/long of 0,0 and then the next would be in real world terms like a centimeter away, but in the game world I would scale that up so it looks further away? apart from that regarding your village distance table, you mean when a new village is added calculate it's distance to all other villages and store those distances?

Comment: @Phil: geoPoints is based on a round earth, yes. While the difference in absolute error between Euclidean grid and a round earth may be small enough as long as you keep the distances small, and while using it can make this specific problem easier; in the end of the day it's doing the wrong calculation, and you would avoid many troubles down the road by using the right one from the start.